# How to write \overset{\circ}{W}_2^{1,1} so that superscript looks good?

Tags: spacing

I'm trying to write `\overset{\circ}{W}_2^{1,1}` so that the circle lies on top of `W` AND the `{1,1}` superscript is not spaced differently due to putting the circle on `W`. So effectively I want the superscript `{1,1}` to appear as it would appear if I did not write the circle on top of `W`. Suggestions?

Comment: `\mathring{W}_2^{1,1}`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
You have
$\overset{\circ}{W}_2^{1,1}$

You want to
$\overset{\circ}{W}{}_2^{1,1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please observe that sub- and superscripts are now the arguments of `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX kernel contains the accent `\mathring`. If you want to have a bigger ring, you can use the `\accentset` command (from `accents`), which will ensure proper vertical spacing between the letter and its accent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,  accents}

\begin{document}

You have
$\overset{\circ}{W}_2^{1,1}$\bigskip

Maybe you want\medskip

\verb|\mathring|: $\quad  \mathring{W}_2^{1,1} $, or \medskip

\verb|\accentset|$: \quad \accentset{\circ}{W}_2^{1,1} $ or $ \accentset{\scriptstyle\circ}{W}_2^{1,1} $
or even $ \accentset{\textstyle\circ}{W}_2^{1,1} $.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You answered the question I linked as duplicate!

Comment: @egreg: I suppose it was not yet marked so when I posted (maybe a matter of second?). I'll remove it in a moment. Sorry.

Comment: Don't remove it.